# Splitting shards results into empty shards in Solr

Tags: solr, sharding, solrcloud

## Use-case

We're running Solr in a very simplistic multi-node setup with multiple indexes that contain a single shard each. Each shard is replicated across all nodes. Every index contains over 1 billion documents. We've seen a decline in performance and wish to increase the amount of nodes but also split up the indexes in multiple shards to finetune each index optimally.

## Test setup

I've made a test environment of 3 nodes with a single index that has a single shard and contains of 10 million documents.

I've created the test collection that has a `compositeId` router with the following request:

```
POST http://10.0.0.11:8983/api/collections
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "create": {
    "name": "test",
    "router": {
      "field": "Id"
    },
    "numShards": 1,
    "replicationFactor": 3,
    "maxShardsPerNode": 5
  }
}
```

## Steps I've taken

According to the documentation, splitting a shard should be relatively easy without performing any additional commits or whatsoever and would not cause any downtime.

Then I perform the splitting shard action to split it up and replicate across multiple nodes

```
GET http://10.0.0.11:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=SPLITSHARD
    &collection=test
    &shard=shard1
    &timing=true
    &numSubShards=3
```

Comes with the following response:

```
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 6399
  },
  "success": {
    "10.0.0.11:8983_solr": {
      "responseHeader": {
        "status": 0,
        "QTime": 363
      },
      "core": "test_shard1_0_replica_n7"
    },
    "10.0.0.11:8983_solr": {
      "responseHeader": {
        "status": 0,
        "QTime": 297
      },
      "core": "test_shard1_1_replica_n8"
    },
    "10.0.0.11:8983_solr": {
      "responseHeader": {
        "status": 0,
        "QTime": 318
      },
      "core": "test_shard1_2_replica_n9"
    },
    "10.0.0.11:8983_solr": {
      "responseHeader": {
        "status": 0,
        "QTime": 0
      }
    },
    "10.0.0.11:8983_solr": {
      "responseHeader": {
        "status": 0,
        "QTime": 0
      }
    },
    "10.0.0.11:8983_solr": {
      "responseHeader": {
        "status": 0,
        "QTime": 99
      }
    },
    "10.0.0.11:8983_solr": {
      "responseHeader": {
        "status": 0,
        "QTime": 145
      },
      "response": [
        "timing",
        {
          "time": 129.0,
          "doSplit": {
            "time": 129.0
          },
          "findDocSetsPerLeaf": {
            "time": 3.0
          },
          "addIndexes": {
            "time": 109.0
          },
          "subIWCommit": {
            "time": 13.0
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "10.0.0.11:8983_solr": {
      "responseHeader": {
        "status": 0,
        "QTime": 0
      },
      "core": "test_shard1_0_replica_n7",
      "status": "EMPTY_BUFFER"
    },
    "10.0.0.11:8983_solr": {
      "responseHeader": {
        "status": 0,
        "QTime": 0
      },
      "core": "test_shard1_2_replica_n9",
      "status": "EMPTY_BUFFER"
    },
    "10.0.0.11:8983_solr": {
      "responseHeader": {
        "status": 0,
        "QTime": 0
      },
      "core": "test_shard1_1_replica_n8",
      "status": "EMPTY_BUFFER"
    },
    "10.0.0.12:8983_solr": {
      "responseHeader": {
        "status": 0,
        "QTime": 213
      },
      "core": "test_shard1_0_replica_n0"
    },
    "10.0.0.13:8983_solr": {
      "responseHeader": {
        "status": 0,
        "QTime": 266
      },
      "core": "test_shard1_0_replica_n1"
    },
    "10.0.0.11:8983_solr": {
      "responseHeader": {
        "status": 0,
        "QTime": 144
      },
      "core": "test_shard1_1_replica_n0"
    },
    "10.0.0.12:8983_solr": {
      "responseHeader": {
        "status": 0,
        "QTime": 199
      },
      "core": "test_shard1_1_replica_n1"
    },
    "10.0.0.13:8983_solr": {
      "responseHeader": {
        "status": 0,
        "QTime": 167
      },
      "core": "test_shard1_2_replica_n0"
    },
    "10.0.0.11:8983_solr": {
      "responseHeader": {
        "status": 0,
        "QTime": 200
      },
      "core": "test_shard1_2_replica_n1"
    },
    "http://10.0.0.11:8983/solr/test_shard1_replica_n1/": {
      "responseHeader": {
        "status": 0,
        "QTime": 28
      }
    }
  },
  "timing": {
    "time": 6384.0,
    "checkDiskSpace": {
      "time": 43.0
    },
    "fillRanges": {
      "time": 5.0
    },
    "createSubSlicesAndLeadersInState": {
      "time": 4607.0
    },
    "waitForSubSliceLeadersAlive": {
      "time": 101.0
    },
    "splitParentCore": {
      "time": 146.0
    },
    "applyBufferedUpdates": {
      "time": 1.0
    },
    "identifyNodesForReplicas": {
      "time": 0.0
    },
    "createReplicaPlaceholders": {
      "time": 20.0
    },
    "createCoresForReplicas": {
      "time": 1415.0
    },
    "finalCommit": {
      "time": 34.0
    }
  }
}
```

When the action was completed in 6 secs (which I think is way too low for splitting a shard that contains 10 million documents), I queried the collection and it returns 0 results. Looking in the data folder of each node also shows no Lucene files.

The logging shows no error or something eyecatching that indicates that the operation went wrong.

- Removed the collection and recreated the collection numerous times with the same data
- Looked through the logging from the start until the end of the splitshard action
- Double checked if there was enough storage available to perform the splitshard action
- Double checked if the new shards became active and were healthy

## Leading up to my question

Does anyone have any idea on how to tackle this issue or how to dig deeper on why it's going sideways?

Alternatively we may start looking into reindexing the collection which causes some sort of downtime.

## Update 1:

Removing the router.field from the collection properties solved the issue but I'd still like to know the root cause why this property specifically causes issues when splitting a shard.

When the `router.field` was still configured, I checked the collection status:

```
GET http://10.0.0.11:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=COLSTATUS
    &collection=test
    &coreInfo=true
    &segments=true
    &fieldInfo=true
    &sizeInfo=true
```

And responded with this partial:

```
"properties": {
  "autoAddReplicas": "false",
  "maxShardsPerNode": "5",
  "nrtReplicas": "3",
  "pullReplicas": "0",
  "replicationFactor": "3",
  "router": {
    "field": "Id",
    "name": "compositeId"
  },
  "tlogReplicas": "0"
},
```

As you can see in the partial response, the router is still `compositeId`.